# Получить данные из forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

Мне нужно получить результат из forEach для дальнейшего использования. Знаю, что надо делать через замыкание. Но тема тяжело дается, а без простого явного примера не могу понять.

```
const tasks = [
      {
        id: '1138465078061',
        text: 'Посмотреть новый урок по JavaScript',
      },
      {
        id: '1138465078062',
        text: 'Выполнить тест после урока',
      },
    ]
    
    tasks.forEach((item) => {item.text})
```

Comment: `.foeEach` просто перебирает массив, но ничего не возвращает. Замыкание тут не пойму куда пристроить. Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Причём тут замыкания и foreach который никак не возвращает результат? Поясните что вы делаете и что придумали такое

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 
Хочу получить результат text из массива

Comment: для этого нужно использовать map а не forEach  при этом фигурные скобки нужно будет опустить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский map возвращает массив со всеми элементами. А хочется, чтобы он вернул все значения, но по отдельности. Я думал forEach справится с этой задачей

Comment: Нет, map вернёт массив с теми элементами, которые нужно. Например только массив текстов..... Если бы  map возвращал массив со всеми значениями, то в нём не было бы смысла, т.к. зачем возвращать тот же самый массив?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let obj of tasks) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

или

```
tasks.map((obj) => console.log(obj));
```